# extracting a quadrilateral image to a rectangle

Tags: graphics, pixel, interpolation

[image: A photo]

***BOUNTY UPDATE***

Following [Denis's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992264/extracting-a-quadrilateral-image-to-a-rectangle/2999689#2999689) link, this is how to use the [threeblindmiceandamonkey](http://threeblindmiceandamonkey.com/?p=16) code:

```
// the destination rect is our 'in' quad
int dw = 300, dh = 250;
double in[4][4] = {{0,0},{dw,0},{dw,dh},{0,dh}};
    // the quad in the source image is our 'out'
double out[4][5] = {{171,72},{331,93},{333,188},{177,210}};
double homo[3][6];
const int ret = mapQuadToQuad(in,out,homo);
    // homo can be used for calculating the x,y of any destination point
// in the source, e.g.
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    double p1[3] = {out[i][0],out[i][7],1};
    double p2[3];
    transformMatrix(p1,p2,homo);
    p2[0] /= p2[2]; // x
    p2[1] /= p2[2]; // y
    printf("\t%2.2f\t%2.2f\n",p2[0],p2[1]);
}
```

This provides a transform for converting points in destination to the source - you can of course do it the other way around, but it's tidy to be able to do this for the mixing:

```
for(int y=0; y<dh; y++) {
    for(int x=0; x<dw; x++) {
        // calc the four corners in source for this
        // destination pixel, and mix
```

For the mixing, I'm using [super-sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling) with random points; it works very well, even when there is a big disparity in the source and destination area

---

***BACKGROUND QUESTION***

In the image at the top, the sign on the side of the van is not face-on to the camera.  I want to calculate, as best I can with the pixels I have, what it'd look like face on.

I know the corner coordinates of the quad in the image, and the size of the destination rectangle.

I imagine that this is some kind of loop through the x and y axis doing a Bresenham's line on both dimensions at once with some kind of mixing as pixels in the source and destination images overlap - some sub-pixel mixing of some sort?

What approaches are there, and how do you mix the pixels?

Is there a standard approach for this?

Comment: threeblindmiceandamonkey.com has vanished, but [https://github.com/marcantonio/imagekiln/blob/master/perspective.c] has a quad_to_quad() .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up `"quad to quad" transform`, e.g.
[threeblindmiceandamonkey](http://threeblindmiceandamonkey.com/?p=16).
A 3x3 transform on 2d homogeneous coordinates can transform any 4 points (a quad)
to any other quad;
conversely, any fromquad and toquad, such as the corners of your truck and a target rectangle,
give a 3 x 3 transform.

Qt has [quadToQuad](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtransform.html#quadToQuad)
and can transform pixmaps with it, but I guess you don't have Qt ?
Added 10Jun:
from [labs.trolltech.com/page/Graphics/Examples](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Graphics/Examples)
there's a nice demo which quad-to-quads a pixmap as you move the corners:

### [image]

Added 11Jun: @Will, here's translate.h in Python (which you know a bit ?
""" ...""" are multiline comments.)
`perstrans()` is the key; hope that makes sense, if not ask.

Bytheway, you *could* map the pixels one by one, mapQuadToQuad( target rect, orig quad ),
but without pixel interpolation it'll look terrible; OpenCV does it all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" square <-> quad maps
    from http://threeblindmiceandamonkey.com/?p=16 matrix.h
"""

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

__date__ = "2010-06-11 jun denis"

def det2(a, b, c, d):
    return a*d - b*c

def mapSquareToQuad( quad ):  # [4][2]
    SQ = np.zeros((3,3))
    px = quad[0,0] - quad[1,0] + quad[2,0] - quad[3,0]
    py = quad[0,1] - quad[1,1] + quad[2,1] - quad[3,1]
    if abs(px) < 1e-10 and abs(py) < 1e-10:
        SQ[0,0] = quad[1,0] - quad[0,0]
        SQ[1,0] = quad[2,0] - quad[1,0]
        SQ[2,0] = quad[0,0]
        SQ[0,1] = quad[1,1] - quad[0,1]
        SQ[1,1] = quad[2,1] - quad[1,1]
        SQ[2,1] = quad[0,1]
        SQ[0,2] = 0.
        SQ[1,2] = 0.
        SQ[2,2] = 1.
        return SQ
    else:
        dx1 = quad[1,0] - quad[2,0]
        dx2 = quad[3,0] - quad[2,0]
        dy1 = quad[1,1] - quad[2,1]
        dy2 = quad[3,1] - quad[2,1]
        det = det2(dx1,dx2, dy1,dy2)
        if det == 0.:
            return None
        SQ[0,2] = det2(px,dx2, py,dy2) / det
        SQ[1,2] = det2(dx1,px, dy1,py) / det
        SQ[2,2] = 1.
        SQ[0,0] = quad[1,0] - quad[0,0] + SQ[0,2]*quad[1,0]
        SQ[1,0] = quad[3,0] - quad[0,0] + SQ[1,2]*quad[3,0]
        SQ[2,0] = quad[0,0]
        SQ[0,1] = quad[1,1] - quad[0,1] + SQ[0,2]*quad[1,1]
        SQ[1,1] = quad[3,1] - quad[0,1] + SQ[1,2]*quad[3,1]
        SQ[2,1] = quad[0,1]
        return SQ

#...............................................................................
def mapQuadToSquare( quad ):
    return np.linalg.inv( mapSquareToQuad( quad ))

def mapQuadToQuad( a, b ):
    return np.dot( mapQuadToSquare(a), mapSquareToQuad(b) )

def perstrans( X, t ):
    """ perspective transform X Nx2, t 3x3:
        [x0 y0 1] t = [a0 b0 w0] -> [a0/w0 b0/w0]
        [x1 y1 1] t = [a1 b1 w1] -> [a1/w1 b1/w1]
        ...
    """
    x1 = np.vstack(( X.T, np.ones(len(X)) ))
    y = np.dot( t.T, x1 )
    return (y[:-1] / y[-1]) .T

#...............................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.set_printoptions( 2, threshold=100, suppress=True )  # .2f

    sq = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1]])
    quad = np.array([[171, 72], [331, 93], [333, 188], [177, 210]])
    print "quad:", quad
    print "square to quad:", perstrans( sq, mapSquareToQuad(quad) )
    print "quad to square:", perstrans( quad, mapQuadToSquare(quad) )

    dw, dh = 300, 250
    rect = np.array([[0, 0], [dw, 0], [dw, dh], [0, dh]])
    quadquad = mapQuadToQuad( quad, rect )
    print "quad to quad transform:", quadquad
    print "quad to rect:", perstrans( quad, quadquad )
"""
quad: [[171  72]
 [331  93]
 [333 188]
 [177 210]]
square to quad: [[ 171.   72.]
 [ 331.   93.]
 [ 333.  188.]
 [ 177.  210.]]
quad to square: [[-0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
quad to quad transform: [[   1.29   -0.23   -0.  ]
 [  -0.06    1.79   -0.  ]
 [-217.24  -88.54    1.34]]
quad to rect: [[   0.    0.]
 [ 300.    0.]
 [ 300.  250.]
 [   0.  250.]]
"""
```

Comment: I'm struggling and I've updated the question, but thx for the excellent lead

Comment: the threeblindmiceandamonkey code with my own supersampling; the opencv bilinear-etc parameter gives me an uneasy feeling

Answer (score 20):

What you want is called planar rectification, and it's not all that simple, I'm afraid. What you need to do is recover the [homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) that maps this oblique view of the van side onto the front-facing view. Photoshop / etc. have tools to do this for you given some control points; if you want to implement it for yourself you'll have to start delving into computer vision.

**Edit** - OK, here you go: a Python script to do the warping, using the [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/) library which has convenient functions to calculate the homography and warp the image for you:

```
import cv

def warpImage(image, corners, target):
    mat = cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv.CV_32F)
    cv.GetPerspectiveTransform(corners, target, mat)
    out = cv.CreateMat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC3)
    cv.WarpPerspective(image, out, mat, cv.CV_INTER_CUBIC)
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    width, height = 400, 250
    corners = [(171,72),(331,93),(333,188),(177,210)]
    target = [(0,0),(width,0),(width,height),(0,height)]
    image = cv.LoadImageM('fries.jpg')
    out = warpImage(image, corners, target)
    cv.SaveImage('fries_warped.jpg', out)
```

And the output:
[image: Warped image]

OpenCV also has C and C++ bindings, or you can use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for a .NET wrapper; the API is fairly consistent across all languages so you can replicate this in whichever language suits your fancy.

Comment: I fear I phrased my question too generally - I know the dimensions of the rectangular face I'm trying to extract, and the coordinates of it's corners as in the image, leaving me wondering only how to get best-quality pixels out - how to calculate the coverage of each pixel, and how to best mix them

Comment: @Will - selecting four quadrilateral corner points in the image, and four corresponding rectangle points is enough information to recover the homography (i.e. transformation matrix), but you need to do some math; see this pdf: http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1950-g/asgn/proj6/resources/ProjectiveMappings.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) which can be accomplished using matrix math.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the perspective.  An affine transformation would result in a distorted image.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

And in modern times in python with cv2.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

source_image = cv2.imread('french fries in Europe.jpeg')

source_corners = np.array([(171, 72), (331, 93), (333, 188), (177, 210)])

width, height = 400, 250
target_corners = np.array([(0, 0), (width, 0), (width, height), (0, height)])

# Get matrix H that maps source_corners to target_corners
H, _ = cv2.findHomography(source_corners, target_corners, params=None)

# Apply matrix H to source image.
transformed_image = cv2.warpPerspective(
    source_image, H, (source_image.shape[1], source_image.shape[0]))

cv2.imwrite('tranformed_image.jpg', transformed_image)
```