# Pose estimation for rectangle in flash application

Tags: flash, math, geometry, transformation, augmented-reality

I'm working on a simple augmenter reality application and my question is:

Is there any simple algorithm or library out there that could help me to determine rotation and perspective of a plane where my test object (black rectangle) is located.

I basically grab a frame from webcam and then mark the corners of a test object. Now i know the position of every corner in camera focal plane and of course i also know the position of the corners of the test object on paper plane. What i want to know is what kind of rotations I should make to reach the situation on the photo. In case of multiple paths, for me...any of them is suitable.

I plan to render some photos onto that plane (which I can't define at the moment) with Five3D AS3 library.

Comment: Questions like this have come up before. Do you know how to convert points in the focal plane into ray angles? Do you know how to represent the rotations?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705195/is-there-an-algorithm-for-solving-such-projection-reconstruction-geometric-proble ?

Comment: Or this: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217370/how-can-i-project-an-arbitrary-plane-identified-by-4-points-unto-a-2d-plane ?

Comment: Tnx! I made a mistake while solving the equation for transformations. Got it solved thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992264/extracting-a-quadrilateral-image-to-a-rectangle

Comment: Take a look at this [augmented reality list](http://www.as3gamegears.com/category/augmented-reality). You may find some useful lib to help you.

Comment: What information do you already know? Camera field of view? Lens distortion?

Answer (score 1):

FlarManager (http://words.transmote.com/wp/flarmanager/) is what you're looking for. tutorial: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=114